# Why does my background image keep changing on different screen sizes?

Tags: php, css

My website's background image keeps changing on page resize. I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. Here's my code:

```
header {
  background-image: url('../img/header-bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: If there any media query on your css? Please do inspect on the element to see what cause the image to be change.

Comment: please create a code snippet of working code